# How can I create a linked list where one node is pointing to more than one other note?

Tags: c++

Similar to this example:

[image]

I wanna make a linked list node connections as shown in the picture but I am stuck, how should I proceed?

```
class Node{

public:
    int id;
    int count;
    int *next;
    int *prev;
    Node(int a): id(a), count(0), next(NULL), prev(NULL) {};
    Node(const int & ss, const int &c): id(ss), count( c), next(NULL), prev(NULL) {};
```

Right now I have these and some other setter and getter functions.

Answer (score 3):

That picture is a [graph adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) where:

1. There is an array of 5 elements, one per graph node.
2. Each array element is a (singly linked) list of adjacent node numbers.
3. The value of each list element is the graph node number this graph node is adjacent to.

`Node* adjacency_list[5]` is enough to represent that.

Working example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Node {
public:
    int id;
    Node *next;
    Node *prev;
    Node(int a): id(a), next(0), prev(0) {}
};

Node* make_list(std::initializer_list<int> ids) {
    Node* head = 0;
    Node** ptail = &head;
    for(int id : ids) {
        *ptail = new Node(id - 1);
        ptail = &((**ptail).next);
    }
    return head;
}

void print_list(Node** heads, int count) {
    for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        std::cout << (i + 1) << ": ";
        for(Node* n = heads[i]; n; n = n->next)
            std::cout << (n->id + 1) << ',';
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    Node* adjacency_list[5] = {};
    adjacency_list[1 - 1] = make_list({2, 3, 4});
    adjacency_list[2 - 1] = make_list({4, 5});
    adjacency_list[3 - 1] = make_list({1, 2, 5});
    adjacency_list[4 - 1] = make_list({5});
    adjacency_list[5 - 1] = make_list({4});
    print_list(adjacency_list, 5);
}
```

Output:

```
1: 2,3,4,
2: 4,5,
3: 1,2,5,
4: 5,
5: 4,
```

In a real-world application you may like to make sure that the allocated memory doesn't leak (it leaks in this example) or use [`std::forward_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) or some other standard or 3rd-party container.

Comment: So should I make an array for followers? If so, would dynamic memory allocation be better in case I want to add more nodes? Thank you.

Comment: @ExperiencedSoup `followers` is a linked list, and your `Node` is a linked list element. Each `Node` must be allocated from the heap, with `new Node`. You need code to append list nodes to the list represented as `Node*`.